# Local variable ternary assignment in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I have a slim partial like so:

```
- name = (defined?(name) ? name : 'tags')
- id = (defined?(id) ? id : ('input-' + name))
- label = defined?(label) ? label : nil
- placeholder = defined?(placeholder) ? placeholder : nil
- className = defined?(className) ? className : nil
- prefetch = defined?(prefetch) ? prefetch : nil
- displayKey = defined?(displayKey) ? displayKey : nil
- valueKey = defined?(valueKey) ? valueKey : nil

.input-container.tags
  - if label
    label for="#{id}" = label
  input type="text" id="#{id}" name="#{name}" placeholder="#{placeholder}" data-prefetch="#{prefetch}" data-displayKey="#{displayKey}" data-valueKey="#{valueKey}"
```

When I use it (via ==render) and pass locals inside — everything is ok.

But when I omit, for example, name - it is not assigning to default 'tags'. And the same is for id. They are simply empty. If I comment out assignments in the beginning — undefined variable error raises, as expected.

What is wrong with assignments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need slim. Just `irb` the code:

```
name = (defined?(name) ? name : 'tags')
p name #=> nil
```

It does not work, because you implicitly define `name` on the left side of the statement `name = ...`. So when Ruby interpreter evaluates `defined?(name)` it gives truly result.

I think you already get the answer:

```
unless defined?(name)
  name = 'tags'
end
```

or shorter:

```
name ||= 'tags'
```

Comment: Oh, great, `- name ||= 'tags'` works and very convenient. Also single line `- unless defined?(name) then name = 'tags'` makes the deal. But why ternary doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Because you actually define `name` before `define?(name)` being called. `name = ...`

Comment: Very strange behaviour... One more strangeness in ruby =)) Thank you for explanation

Comment: actually it's very beautiful :)))

Comment: @ВладимирКорнилов I've added description of the behaviour in my answer.

Comment: Thank you ) It is weird, because in other languages assignments are evaluated from right to left and this has many advantages as I think.. But this is an offtop =)